# Why do /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base contents not appear in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I am using `openresolv` 3.7.2-1 in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus).
Modifying `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and running `resolvconf -u`
updates `/etc/resolv.conf` but modifying `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`
and running `resolvconf -u` does not update `/etc/resolv.conf`. Why is this?